# No veo la opcion de Win32 en c++ en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++

Podrian ayudarme ¿Porque no veo la opcion de win32 en c++? he instalado todo lo de desarrollo para escritorio e desinstalado y vuelto a instalar pero aun asi no se visualiza.

Aqui les dejo una imagen. Espero puedan ayudarme.

http://img.fenixzone.net/i/KJ7Dsom.png

Comment: Si compilas en Windows, el resultado será un programa Win32, a no ser que escojas "Multiplataforma".

Answer (score 0):

La opción de compilar en 32 o b4 bits no se encuentra en la plantilla sino en la información de *Linker*.

Visual Studio te deja crear diferentes configuraciones bajo la opción de *Platform*. Bajo este contexto puedes tener una configuración para 32 bits y otra para 64 y cambiar de una a otra sin dificultad... hay tutoriales que explican como hacer esto así que no voy a entrar en detalles aquí.

Para elegir de forma manual la compilación en 32 bits tienes que seleccionar el proyecto (ojo, no la solución) y, en el menú contextual, ir a las propiedades del proyecto. Se abre una ventana con un arbol a la izquierda... despliega la opción *Linker* (o como se diga en español, lo siento pero tengo la versión inglesa instalada). Ahí busca una opción que diga *Advanced* y selecciónala.

En la lista de atributos de la derecha, busca uno que dice *Target machine* y elige la opción *MachineX86*.

Answer (score 0):

Que extraño, lo que pasa es que cuando yo realizaba la instalación de VS2013 Ultimate + MSDN siempre me salia esta opción de proyecto.

http://img.fenixzone.net/i/wYa0uOf.png

Pero en el VS 2017 no me sale dicha opcion para realizarlo. ¿Podrian aclararme esta duda?